# Deployment Issue with Bing Text Translate API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am a technical author and want to trial machine translation with MadCap Lingo.  I went to Bing Translate and followed instructions for setting up an azure account.  I then filled in the form to deploy Translate Text API to my azure account.  The first attempt failed.l  I don't think it liked my service name.   The second attempt sat running for over an hour and I had an error message displaying saying Gate Way failure.   The Cognitive Services service did not respond.  So I cancelled that deployment.  I tried to fill in the form again but Azure thinks I already have a free deployment and wont let me complete the deployment request.  I went back to the dashboard and there are no deployments displaying.  So how do I get my trial of Translate text working so I can get a key and link MadCap Lingo to the service?

Comment: OK.  I have gone back in and deleted the second attempt at deployment the gone back to the first attempt.  Azure allowed me to redeploy successfully.   

I looked at the subscription details and it says I am over quota.  I have not translated anything yet!  So what does this mean?

Comment: I went to the keys section and I appear to have two keys.  I tried entering one into Madcap Lingo and all I got was a load of errors.  Not sure if the over quota is because I have somehow aquired two keys or something else.

Comment: All this faffing around is very frustrating.

Comment: Spent 30 mins on google and I have translations working in MadCap Lingo.  It was much easier to set up and I did not encounter any glitches.

Comment: I just did the same, and I'm already "over quota" on the free tier as well. I just bumped to a standard tier for testing and that helped. Minimum $10 charge, but that's not too much. Bummer the Free tier for trying it out is broken.